# displaying data in asp gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I'm having this issue on displaying data into gridview.  I want to display data from **BindData** into a custom made gridview as below. I have already tried 
write the code on same page as html > working(but my senior engineer does not want that), so now I need to redo it by use back-end code and pass those (ID,Name,Age) into those label ID using dataset. how can I accomplished this?

```
<asp:GridView ID="MyGridView" runat="server" CellPadding="5" CssClass="ControlStyle" 
ForeColor="#333333" Font-Size="8px" GridLines="Vertical" width="40%" CaptionAlign="Left" 
PageSize="15" AllowPaging="True" OnPageIndexChanging="MyData_OnPageIndexChanging" 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" enableEventValidation="false">       
    <Columns >                                 
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:ImageButton ID="img" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/Images/arrow-2a.png" />
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>  
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ID">
          <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lbl_ID" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase"></asp:Label>                      
          </ItemTemplate>
      </asp:TemplateField>                                             
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Name" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase"></asp:Label>      
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
     <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Age">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="lbl_Age" runat="server" Font-Size="10px" CssClass="ControlStyleUpperCase"></asp:Label>      
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

and I want to display below data.

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Me.BindData()
End If
End Sub
Private Sub BindData()
Dim sCon As String = "MyConnectionString"

Using con As New SqlConnection(sCon)
    Using cmd As New SqlCommand(" select * from users ")

        Dim sda As New SqlDataAdapter()

        Try
            cmd.Connection = con : con.Open()
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd

            Dim dt As New DataTable
            sda.Fill(dt)

            'BIND DATABASE WITH THE GRIDVIEW.
            MyGridView.DataSource = dt
            MyGridView.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            txtMsg.Text = ex.Message
        End Try
    End Using
End Using
End Sub
```

with above code, my page show nothing, just white canvas, where did I do wrong? please guide.

thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is the meaning of "white canvas"? Is it just showing blank page without any grid shown, or the data is not bound to the grid?

Comment: yes, just a blank page without anything shown...by right, this page should display those grid's only.

Comment: you need to set label's Text property with datatable columnName or use asp:BoundField instead of asp:TemplateField

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your kind effort, I've manage to solve this issue by modified my code from this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
If Not Me.IsPostBack Then
    Me.BindData()
End If
End Sub
```

into this

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load   
If Not IsPostBack Then
    BindData()
End If
End Sub
```

I still don't know whats the different between those two but I've manage to get my results as expected.

Comment: First of all data is there in users table?